# How compile gSoap with NTLM support? (Mac OS X)

Tags: c++, macos, ntlm, gsoap

Need help to build gSoap with NTML support (Mac OS X). Can't find any tutorials about this. In documentation I find just:

> HTTP NTLM authentication is enabled at the client-side by installing libntlm from http://www.nongnu.org/libntlm and compiling all project source codes with -DWITH_NTLM.

Could somebody explain in more details what to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't get much better description than that. First, do those two things: Download and install libntlm and add "WITH_NTLM" definition to the compilation of your project.

Few more things I've done when building a (g)soap client (unfortunately, in visual studio):

- pointed compiler to the "LibNTLM\include" as additional include directory
- pointed linker to the library file ("\LibNTLM\lib\libntlm.dll.a" in my case).

Comment: Any idea if this Libntlm library is still viable on x64 architectures for MacOS, and under Xcode 9? also, does it also depend externally on openSSL to be present? (because that was removed from OSX SDK a while ago).

Comment: Sorry, no idea.